# Cross compile OpenCV with CUDA on x86-64 host for nvidia tk1 (arm) target using Yocto Project?

Tags: opencv, cuda, embedded-linux, yocto, tegra

I want to build a custom Linux using the Yocto Project for a system using the nvidia tegra k1 processor, which has an arm cortex A 15 (32bit) and a GPU. Furthermore, OpenCV (version >= 3.0) with CUDA support needs to be installed.

Now when Bitbake tries to compile OpenCV with CUDA it crashes because nvcc throws an error `Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")` which [I learned](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/407707/nvcc-does-not-work/) is usually the case if you try to run an nvcc binary that is for the wrong system (e.g. 32bit-nvcc on 64bit-system). So I guess it just runs the nvcc that is suppost for the target system and therefore crashes.

1. I don't know whether I need to compile using the usual x86-64bit-nvcc of the host system or (if this exists) some cross-compilation-nvcc.
2. I need to know how I can involve said compiler into bitbake's process that builds OpenCV.

Comment: can you use openCV4tegra? Afaik it is much better optimized than plain cuda opencv

Comment: OpenCV4tegra is not an option since an OpenCV version of 3.0 or higher is required. Afaik OpenCV4tegra releases are all 2.4.X.

Comment: Have a look at the 2nd version in http://elinux.org/Jetson/Installing_OpenCV on how to compile openCV for tk1.

Comment: There is no actual information on cross-compiling at that page except for what it means or am I missing something?

Comment: so your question is about how cross compiling can be used at all?

Comment: My question is about how I can use the host system's nvcc to cross compile while bitbaking OpenCV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

1. One needs to use an nvcc binary that supports the host architecture. To specify the target architecture on can pass it cross compilation flags (see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#cross-compilation). These are passed via the the cmake flag  `-DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS`
2. `EXTRA_OECMAKE_append = "-DCUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE=${PATH_TO_THE_NVCC_BINARY}"`

The whole statement in the bbappend file could look like this

```
EXTRA_OECMAKE_append = " \
    -DCUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE=${NVCC_BINARY} \ 
    -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="--compiler-bindir ${GCC_BINARY}"  \
    "
```